# codesign reports invalid Info.plist on an app dl'ed from the internet. Has the app been possibly compromised?

Tags: macos, applications, security, code-signing

I downloaded an app from github (mac2imgur), and it refused to run.

```
$ codesign -vv mac2imgur.app
mac2imgur.app: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)
In architecture: x86_64
```

It seems unlikely the developer uploaded something with a bad signature.

Is this a red flag that the app may have been compromised and reuploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s quite likely a developer uploaded something incorrectly codesigned. As a developer myself, I know it takes time to get it right, and many don’t bother.